# JSON não retorna utf-8

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Estou usando freegeoip para saber minha localização e usa-la no meu programa, mas quando eu faço uma chamada usando:

```
r = requests.get(location_url, headers={"content-type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
```

O retorno fica assim:

```
{
  ip: "0.0.0.0",
  country_code: "BR",
  country_name: "Brazil",
  region_code: "SP",
  region_name: "Sao Paulo",
  city: "SÃ£o Paulo",
  zip_code: "",
  time_zone: "America/Sao_Paulo",
  latitude: -20.1323,
  longitude: -50.6417,
  metro_code: 0
}
```

Quando eu leio usando `r.text`, eu preciso dos acentos nas palavras. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente decodificar a resposta manualmente:

```
r = requests.get(location_url)
texto = r.content.decode('utf8')
```

Nota: `r.json()` também pode ser útil no seu caso.

Comment: Muito obrigado, desta forma funcionou. Já estava a horas tentando dar decode no text quando poderia dar direto no content

Answer (score 0):

Em vez de usar `UTF-8` tente usar `ISO-8859-1`:

```
r = requests.get(location_url, headers={"content-type":"application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1"})
```

Comment: Continua o mesmo retorno.

Comment: Como está salvando seu arquivo no seu editor de texto?

Comment: Na verdade eu estou printando numa tela mas estou fazendo `location = json.loads(r.text)`

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de `UTF-8` tenta usar o `latin1`. Não sei o motivo, mas tive o mesmo problema e resolveu assim.